# Create container web app without setting linux_fx_version

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I would like to create a container web using terraform. I also would like to deploy it from github. So I need to manage the linux_fx_version property there. When I dont set this in terrraform, I get an error when deploying a container

```
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: This is not a container web app. Please remove inputs like images and configuration-file which are only relevant for container deployment.
```

When I set the property in terraform, terraform would apply this setting when I change my infrastructur.

Is there any way to mark a web app container based, or setting this property only when it is not set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the `linux_fx_version` property after the Azure app service provisioned. you could [configure a custom container for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-windows) with `az webapp config container set`. Also, you could use a `local-exec` Provisioner to invoke a process on the machine running Terraform.

For example, you can provision a Linux App Service which runs multiple Docker Containers from Docker Compose file.

```
provisioner  "local-exec" {
 
command =<<EOT
    az webapp config set \
    --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.main.name} \
    --name ${azurerm_app_service.main.name} \
    --linux-fx-version "COMPOSE|${filebase64("./compose.yml")}"
    EOT
}
```

[image]

Otherwise, to create a web app for containers with terraform, you need to use [linux_fx_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service#linux_fx_version) to define the container to load on start.

If you're not using App Service Slots and Deployments are handled outside of Terraform - it's possible to ignore changes to specific fields in the configuration using `ignore_changes` within Terraform's lifecycle block, for example:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "test" {
  # ...
  site_config = {
    # ...
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|appsvcsample/python-helloworld:0.1.2"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "site_config.0.linux_fx_version", # deployments are made outside of Terraform
    ]
  }
}
```

For more information, read [examples of deploying Web App for Containers (Azure App Service) with terraform](https://github.com/innovationnorway/terraform-azurerm-web-app-container#web-app-for-containers-azure-app-service)  and [examples of using the App Service Resources](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/tree/master/examples/app-service).